# Alpine.js - Show an input field and add focus to it at the same time

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I have a button, and when a user clicks it, an input element should be shown and it should have focus.

I tried this:

```html
<div x-data="{ show: false }">

    <input x-show="show" type="text" id="input" x-ref="input" />

    <button @click="show = !show; $refs.input.focus();">Button</button>

</div>
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Are you sure alpine.js is being loaded correctly ? Because I've copied / pasted your code in a fiddle with alpine.js and it is working fine

Comment: Yes I am. You can check out this editor: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GQEY8EWSLJHB When I click the button, the input should show and have focus

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand that the not-working part was the focus. Craig E's answer below is the correct one (you may use `setTimeout` as well)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To put focus on the input immediately after showing it, you'll need to use Alpine's $nextTick function. Try this slightly altered version of your code:

```
<div x-data="{ show: false }">

    <input x-show="show" type="text" id="input" x-ref="input" />

    <button @click="show = !show; $nextTick(() => { $refs.input.focus(); });">Button</button>

</div>
```

Here's some more info about $nextTick: https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine#nexttick